# Are there guiding principles as to which activation functions suit a given RL algorithm?

Tags: neural-networks, reinforcement-learning, deep-rl, activation-functions, hyperparameter-optimization

Are there rules of thumb as to which activation functions work well (or which one would not) on the policy and value network of a class of RL algorithms? For hidden layers and for the output layer.

For example, I came across [[1](https://arxiv.org/abs/2103.17258)], which mentions ELU to be indispensable to MPO [[2](https://arxiv.org/abs/1806.06920)], and tanh (output activation) to be indispensable to SAC's Gaussian policy.